# Bash parameter expansion and array index operations

Tags: arrays, bash, parameters

The `${parameter,,pattern}` parameter expansion converts alphabetic characters in *parameter* to lower-case.

On **cygwin 1.7.11-1 Bash 4.1.10(4)** and also on my **debian squeeze Bash 4.1.5(1)**;

if i run the following, i get a curious result:

```
$ declare -a a=(Zero One Two Three); n=0; echo "${a[n],,}->${n}"; echo "${a[++n]}->${n}"; echo "${a[++n],,}->${n}"
zero->0
One->1
three->3
$
```

NB: similar results happen:

 for `,,*` or `^^` case conversion;

 for some other expansions such as `${parameter##word}`; 

 for using either prefix/postfix `++` or `--` operator; 

 for using `$((++n))` instead of just `++n`.

However, the length expansion `${#parameter}` works as i might expect:

in the above snippet, `echo "${#a[++n]}->${n}"` instead of `echo "${a[++n],,}->${n}` would yield `3->2` instead of `three->3` ~& the length of a[2]="two" is indeed 3 characters.

I imagine that the *parameter* expansion is happening twice. But why is this happening?

Comment: Do you mean why the re-order of values on array iteration?

Comment: i mean exactly that i would expect to get returned:`zero->0
One->1
two->2`

Comment: +1 for a well-investigated question, but I don't think you'll get a good answer, because I think it's simply a bug. On my system, Bash crashes (!) if I add another `"${a[++n],,}"` that *should* move to the last element but *would* (per your results) move one past the end of the array.

Comment: By the way, if you can confirm that it happens in the latest version of Bash, and if no one offers a theory for how it could be anything other than a bug, http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Reporting-Bugs.html has instructions for how to report it.

Comment: [ruakh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh), agreed. it probably should be flagged as a bug -since as you say it can be made to seg-fault. i am grabbing the bash source now & will raise a report once i've taken a look inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grabbed the latest bash source & it appears that this issue is resolved for this version:

```
$ ./bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
$
```

Note however that on my Debian Squeeze *stable*, I have:

```
$ apt-cache policy bash
bash:
  Installed: 4.1-3
  Candidate: 4.1-3
  Version table:
 *** 4.1-3 0
        500 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
```

I think this means that currently on **Debian Squeeze**, the latest stable version of bash is **4.1.5(1)** & contains this bug. Also on **Cygwin 1.7.11-1** currently the latest available bash package appears to be version **4.1.10(4)** & contains this bug. Of course the issue is easy to work around, so no real need to build the **4.2** sources.

Answer (score 0):

I got

```
Zero->0
One->1
Two->2
```

However I think "${a[++n]}->${n}" may not be well defined.

try substitute with

```
let n=$n+1 ; echo "${a[n],,}->${n}";
```

To inject the notion of sequence.

Comment: if you look closely at your results, you will notice that neither the `Zero` nor the `Two` have been converted to lower-case. Now try instead with `echo "${a[++n]foo}->${n}"` same results!. At this point you might want to check your version of bash. For example, on Bash 3.2.25(1) i get the above results also  ;)

Comment: The lowercasing expression is not valid in bash 3.